# SharePoint 2016. How to ensure Kerberos authentication is working properly

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, 2016, kerberos

How to ensure Kerberos authentication for SharePoint 2016 is working properly?

HTTP headers show that Kerberos is used, but [klist](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh134826(v=ws.11).aspx) did not show ticket for SharePoint site. What does it mean?

**Details**

Kerberos for SharePoint 2016 is configured with this blog [SharePoint 2013/2016 Kerberos Authentication](https://www.noralku.net/2016/05/08/sharepoint-20132016-kerberos-authentication/).

If open SharePoint site with IE [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) show this headers

[image]

IE did not prompt authentication window, authentication is automatic as expected. But [klist](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh134826(v=ws.11).aspx) didn't show ticket for SharePoint web

[image]

p.s. I am trying to find a problem with delegation when custom SharePoint-hosted svc service call Exchange EWS. And need to be sure Kerberos on SharePoint is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I will post it here so others and myself could check this Kerberos authentication setting.

According to MSDN, you could check Kerberos login from application server (or whatever server that the client requested) event viewer (Security). I found another [blog](https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/09/26/the-final-kerberos-guide-for-sharepoint-technicians/) that also mention how to check Kerberos working.

If client successfully authenticate using Kerberos it will show

```
Logon Process: Kerberos
Authentication Package: Kerberos
```

[image: Event Viewer]

In KList command it will also display Kerberos, like this picture.

[image: KList]